# Google Analytics Shopping Behavior Analysis Missing Data - duplicate

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, missing

I've created an eCommerce store and created the analytics for this store, On Magento2 backend I've placed the Tracking Code and I start to check that the data is being sent into GA. The enhanced eCommerce is already enabled and collecting order data. The issue is the Shopping Analysis Behavior that is missing data on some steps

Sessions with Product Views

Sessions with Add to Cart

Sessions with Checkout

[image]

Comment: Facing same problem. Found any solution? @David Duong

Comment: I don't find a solution yet.

Comment: We will have to use Enahcned Ecommerce Plugin. That is a paid plugin and will meet our requirements and contain additional data. Have a look at https://www.magepal.com/magento2/extensions/digital-marketing/enhanced-ecommerce-for-google-tag-manager.html

Comment: David please see my recent answer below. This might help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using [this plugin](https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html) (Free Version)

This plugin can provide addToCart and removeFromCart data to google analytics. Hope this helps someone!

Plugin: MAGENTO 2 GOOGLE ANALYTICS ENHANCED ECOMMERCE UA GTM TRACKING
By: WeltPixel
URL: https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce-tag-manager-magento-2.html
[image]
[image]

Comment: I will check it, Thank you!